# Snowflake via API - 400 bad request

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Postman trying to make API work

POST https://jp82090.snowflakecomputing.com/api/v2/statements

Request Headers:

```
User-Agent: MySlackBot/0.1
Accept: application/json
X-Snowflake-Authorization-Token-Type: KEYPAIR_JWT
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJhb__MY_ACTUAL_JWT_TOKEN__CXA
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: f81119ef-9838-4d54-b52e-19ae73c50f37
```

Request BODY

```
{
"statement": "select * from vas limit 10",
"timeout": 60,
"database": "ETF",
"schema": "PUBLIC",
"warehouse": "COMPUTE_WH",
"role": "ACCOUNTADMIN"
}
```

I used

```
SHOW WAREHOUSES;
```

go get the warehouse name because "Click "Warehouses" from within your Snowflake console to view a list of warehouses. This warehouse will be used when Dataform creates runs in Snowflake." from docs does not help - I can not see it anywhere in my UI

I have a response 400 BAD REQUST

Any help would be much appreciated!

I tried

```
POST /api/v2/statements?requestId=8802f1a6-90b3-4ae7-9ce0-2d5fba595908 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: MySlackBot/0.1
Accept: application/json
X-Snowflake-Authorization-Token-Type: KEYPAIR_JWT
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ey_ JWT TOKEN HERE _ww
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 785a1717-bae2-4c08-9a55-ad8647feb5b1
 
{
"statement": "select * from VAS limit 10",
"timeout": 60,
"database": "ETF",
"schema": "PUBLIC",
"warehouse": "COMPUTE_WH",
"role": "ACCOUNTADMIN"
}
 
HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close
```

Answer (score 0):

What instructions/guide are you following?

> go get the warehouse name because "Click "Warehouses" from within your Snowflake console to...

In the Snowsight UI, in the top right from the worksheet UI:

[image]

and about the same place Classic Console. But that said, if you used the command `SHOW WAREHOUSES;` then that part is all good.

Given I am logged in as AccountAdmin, I cannot speak, but, do web-request as that role, is a little crazy, but it also is a good way to prove it's not an ACL problem. Which almost implies the whole warehouse part of the question could be removed from the question. It seems your core problem is why is my API request is not working??

Comment: Thanks! I am following https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/getting_started_snowflake_sql_api/index.html#0 and yes I use 30 day trial just to figure it out before bothering corporate IT with proper access.

Comment: Also, I see no info as to how long the JWT token is valid for and how to refresh it via API but for now, I assume it never expires yet I generate a fresh one every day while figuring this out.

Comment: "It seems your core problem is why is my API request is not working??" YES just warehouse name looked weird to me so I decided to share :)